# How to insert LaTeX with multiple arguments in LyX?

Tags: latex, lyx

I need to insert ERT for
    \SI{-10}{dB}
but I can't seem to do it.  Lyx produces:

```
\SI{-10}\{dB\}
```

How can this be entered in LyX?

Answer (score 0):

It's not intuitive, but it works to

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, type `SI{-10` (LyX inserts the matching `}`).
2. Move to the right of the `}`. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> again.
3. LyX inserts `\`, but then you type `{`, and the `\` is removed, replaced by `{}` pair.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this behaviour, as [I can insert an ERT without problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQvV5.gif).